# What United States state and federal agencies generally participate in aerial weather modification?

Tags: weather, usa, faa

Also wondering which agencies regulate weather modification activities? Any idea where I can find more information about this?

Answer (score 4):

The [North Dakota State Water Commission](http://www.swc.state.nd.us/4dlink9/4dcgi/GetSubCategoryRecord/atmospheric%20resources/ND%20Cloud%20Modification%20Project) runs the North Dakota Cloud Modification Project, which primarily seems to work at reducing hail damage to crops during the thunderstorm season, and has been active (perhaps not continuously) since 1975.

They've got a [section on program evaluations](http://www.swc.state.nd.us/4dlink9/4dcgi/GetContentRecord/PB-292); a peer-reviewed article published in 1997 states:

> [...] the expanded 13-year NDCMP data base showed a 45% decrease in losses in the target area (Smith, et al., 1997).

Their website has a ton of information; a company called [Weather Modification, Inc.](http://www.weathermodification.com/projects.php) is the contractor for ND State and does a lot of other work as well. Either the state or WMI would probably be able to provide additional data.

It may also be worth noting that Russia does lots of weather modification work as well (perhaps more when it was the Soviet Union). No idea how successful any of it is.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_modification#US_National_Oceanic_and_Atmospheric_Administration)

> In the US, the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration keeps records of weather modification projects on behalf of the Secretary of Commerce, under authority of Public Law 92-205, 15 USC § 330B, enacted in 1971

Comment: Thank you, Do you have any information about which agencies engage in weather modification?

Comment: No agencies do it successfully!

Comment: there is a company called EverGreen Air that was contracted out to do some flying and spraying. I used to see a lot of activity over Sheridan, Wy around 2001 -2004 but I do not see it that much any more and really never see it were I moved to. The mountains that ran from outside Billings, Montana to Denver, Co I think were a big experimentation ground for this type of activity.